# Download file using Blob in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, blob, expo

Since React-native `v0.54` and Expo `SDK v26`, Blob is now supported.

I'm trying to download a file available on a URL to my phone (if possible, in my `Downloads` directory on Android)

All I can find for now is an existing solution using `react-native-fetch-blob` which seems not necessary anymore.

If anyone could provide a brief example of how to start implementing this feature on `Expo Snack`

Comment: Not sure when it was added but Expo now has a [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem) API that should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

## Expo

### FileSystem

You can use the `FileSystem` module to download content and save it under a **directory** on your device.

#### Installation

- Managed workflow

`$ expo install expo-file-system`

- Bare workflow

On a bare workflow, please follow the instructions [here](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/).

#### Usage

1. Importing the module

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
```

2. Create a download resumable.

Using **async/await**

```js
await FileSystem.downloadAsync(URI, FILE_URI, OPTIONS);
```

Using **promise**

```js
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4'
)
  .then(({ uri }) => {
    console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

#### NOTE

Keep in mind that in order to save/store the content downloaded, you need to pass a **valid** directory path/uri. i.e `FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4'`. To guarantee that the path to the directory exists, you can use the *FileSystem* module itself to create a directory. Like this:
`await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(path, { intermediates: true });`. The options object takes the **intermediates** property that ensures that if you are trying to create a multilevel directory, it will also create the parent folder (if does not exit) for you.

Answer (score 0):

### XMLHttpRequest

This worked for me. Using the XMLHttpRequest to fetch the file and get the response as a blob.

```
function downloadFile(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              resolve(xhr.response);
          }
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
      xhr.send();
  })
}
```

You can now download a file with

```
downloadFile(YOUR_FILE_URL)
    .then((resolve, reject)=>{console.log((resolve)})
```

[Refrence](https://www.expertmill.com/2018/10/19/using-and-uploading-dynamically-created-local-files-in-react-native-and-expo/)